# Generic way to handle numbers without explicit conversion

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

I have a class which has a property of generic type as given below. Type T can be any number (short, int, float ...)

```
    public class EqualFilter <T> : Filter {
        private T _value;
        public override T Value {
        get {
            return _value;
        }
        set {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_value, value)) {
                _value = value;
                RaiseFilteringChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    .....
}
```

Now I have a client class which has a "String" that needs to be passed to the above setter. Now at the time of setting the value in the above setter, the type T is already determined at runtime and I can get hold of that type as Type T in my client. Is it possible to convert the string to the appropriate type ,as identified by the EqualFilter, in client program? Something like this that is not working

```
Type T = filter.getFilterType();
filter.Value = (T) myTextBox.Text;
```

The below code works but it will involve if-else for all the types that can be numeric.

```
Type T = filter.getFilterType();
if (T == typeof(int)) {
    filter.Value = Int32.Parse(myTextBox.Text);
} else if() {
....
}
```

In short I am not sure how to approach the issue in a better way.

Comment: can you not put a type constraint on `T`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: I am not sure how to approach with the suggestion provided by you. Can you please provide me some detail. Also if I put class constraint on T would that hamper the performance because the filter value will be used in comparasion of values, for a relatively large number of rows.

Comment: it's just a limitation on the Types that `T` accepts. Your current code accepts `T` to be ANY type, you could limit this to a specific interface and have all your accepted Types implement this interface. It's a little unhandy with primitive types but `IComparable` could be good: `where T : IComparable`. You won't need to cast `T` to the actual type before comparison because EVERY `T` that ends up in your method is an `IComparable` so you can safely cast it to `IComparable` and use the `Compare` method: `((IComparable)T).Compare();` rather than all your different casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing something similar to data binding. If all you're interested in is working with strings, you might consider constraining the generic type to `IConvertible` and calling the `Convert.ChangeType` method from a special setter method like so:

```
public class EqualFilter<T> : Filter where T : IConvertible {

    // ... omitted Value property code ...

    public void SetValue(string value)
    {
        Value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }

    // ...
}
```

The generic type constraint permits only those types that [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) can operate upon. Besides the integral and floating point types, this also permits use of the types `string`, `decimal` and `DateTime`. Just be aware that `string` types may not always be exact when working with the `double` type as there can be round-off and floating point representation errors. Also there may be other exceptions that you may want to catch to make this more robust (`FormatException` and `OverflowException`, for instance).

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new EqualFilter<int> { Value = 10 };
    var b = new EqualFilter<double> { Value = 20 };
    b.Value = Math.PI; // RaiseFilteringChanged called - no surprise
    b.SetValue(Math.PI.ToString()); // RaiseFilteringChanged called - surprised?
    Console.WriteLine(b.Value);
    b.SetValue("25");
    Console.WriteLine(b.Value);
    var c = new EqualFilter<DateTime> { Value = DateTime.Today };
    Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
    c.SetValue("12/23/2011");
    Console.WriteLine(c.Value);

    // compiler error object isn't an IConvertible:
    // var illegal = new EqualFilter<object>();
}
```

The big switch statement, in this case, is handled by the framework in the `ChangeType` method.

**Edit:**
Adding the `Console.WriteLine` output from my version of the code above (that has overrides and base-class usage commented-out):

> 3.14159265358979
>
> 25
>
> 4/10/2012 12:00:00 AM
>
> 12/23/2011 12:00:00 AM

Comment: I get Invalid Cast Exception for "Value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));". The string cannot be converted to numeric (int, float,...) using Convert.ChangeType().

Comment: Could you post the code that you're using? In the version that I posted here, I restored portions that I had commented out to make it compile and be testable without having your base class. It worked for me - no invalid cast - so I'm wondering whether there is something else at play that may be obvious if you post the rest of your code.

Comment: Sorry about my earlier comment. Your code works well, so I have marked it as answer. But if you can help me with another related issue. I am using EqualFilter<T> to instantiate types of EqualFilter<int>, EqualFilter<double> and so on for all numeric types based on type of my Model class property. Is it possible to generalise this instantiation, so that I have just one EqualFilter<> instantion line for all numeric types? Similarly when I cast Filter (base class of EqualFilter<>) back to EqualFilter, I just do it once in my code instead of having if else for each type (int,double, etc).

Comment: Yes, this is possible, although I don't know that I have the room in a comment to provide implementations. I like the initializer block approach in the test code I wrote above, but the ugliness/challenge in using this for initializing instance members is that we would end up with redundancies that we would like to eliminate.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
filter.Value = Convert.ChangeType(myTextBox.Text, filter.getFilterType());
```

This won't work if the conversion isn't defined though.

**Edit:**

I didn't notice your `Value` property was generic.
To make this work you could extend your filter object by something like this:

```
public object UnsafeValue
{
    set
    {
        Value = (T)value;
    }
}
```

and assign the result of `Convert.ChangeType` to that property.

Every approach without modifying the filter class would involve either more generics in the call hierarchy or reflection.

Comment: @ConvertType returns object, so I have to cast one to T and compiler does not allows that - "Type or Namespace not found".

Comment: At first seemed like a promising solution, but Value=(T)value fails cast and gives a runtime exception. I think I will have to rethink the approach, perhaps follow what @Bazz has commented and see how that works. In one of the languages that I had worked on, it has a base class Number which encompassed all Numeric types. Using that, it was very easy to handle the situation I am in. But then C# has a whole lot of features that other languages lack and I am quite satisfied with that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a specific setter method like this:

```
public void setValue(object o){
   if (typeof(o) == typeof(Value)) {
       Value = (typeof(Value))o;
   }
}
```

Comment: If that worked, the OP wouldn't have asked in the first place.